# Using rvm and git, can I associate a ruby version with each branch?

Tags: ruby, git, rvm

Is there a way to associate a specific ruby version with a specific branch ?

I would like to have:

```
git checkout branch-a     #ruby -v = 1.8.7
git checkout branch-b     #ruby -v = 1.9.2
```

Thanks

Comment: I know this is an old question. But for others that might find this by googling, this post solves the OPs need: http://gehling.dk/2015/09/automatic-change-rvm-environment-when-switching-git-branch/

Answer (score 3):

You can have different `.rvmrc`s in each branch, but that requires to change the directory to become active.

```
git checkout whatever && cd .
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting up RVM to use .rvmrc and setup automatic reloading of rvmrc files.

After installation of RVM, setup Ruby versions for each branch, eg:

```
rvm --rvmrc --create use ruby-1.8.7
```

Also add the automatic .rvmrc reloading, since .rvmrc files will only be reloaded on cd into a directory otherwise, see this gist: https://gist.github.com/2145979